# Как исправить код, чтобы не было 'String index to var param'?

Tags: delphi, строки, delphi-xe

```
Function exchange(input: String): String;
Var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  Result:=input;
  I:=Length(Result);
  For I:=1 To I Do Begin
    If Result[I]='a' Then Result[I]:='b'; //[DCC Error] test.pas(13): E1047 Unsafe code 'String index to var param'
    If Result[I]='c' Then Result[I]:='d'; //[DCC Error] test.pas(14): E1047 Unsafe code 'String index to var param'
    If Result[I]='e' Then Result[I]:='f'; //[DCC Error] test.pas(15): E1047 Unsafe code 'String index to var param'
  End;
End;
```

Именно изменить, что можно отключить предупреждения я знаю, мне интересно как же пишется этот "надёжный" код и что именно ему тут не нравится?

Comment: Это вообще как? `I:=Length(Result);  For I:=1 To I Do Begin` может хотябы `For I:=1 To Length(Result) Do Begin`, а то как то странно видеть цикл по переменной до значения этой же переменной используя в цикле эту же переменную

Comment: @LamerXaKer я тоже так подумал, но, как ни странно, это валидный код, он компилируется и работает.

Comment: @Kromster, тогда, могу предположить только одно, раз это просто warning, а не exception, то речь о том что размер(кол-во) символов входящей переменной, не определено компилятором во время сборки, что может привести к утечке в случае если переменная счетчика окажется больше размерности входящей строки. Это как бы мы видим на глаз, сколько, и что по идее правильно, а компилятор прямолинеен, указания не было, знать не знаю

Comment: @LamerXaKer тоже не верно. Иначе бы это вылезало при первой же попытке положить длину в переменную - `I:=Length(Result);`.

Comment: @Kromster не, я имею ввиду при обращении к переменной (к символу) по индексу в переменной, компилятор грит несогласен с такой позицией, если мол, мил человек, у тебя I вдруг будет больше размерности длины строки, то как же я дальше жить буду то

Comment: Паскаль сохраняет значение из to и больше не пересчитывает.

Comment: @LamerXaKer обращение к длине строки дает заведомо большее или равное значение чем максимальный индекс.

Comment: @LamerXaKer, "Это вообще как?" Это чтобы на каждом шаге цикла заново не вычислялась длина, стандартный трюк, чтобы для этого не заводить новую переменную, компилируется и работает правильно

Comment: @Isaev Это не трюк, а говнокод. Забудьте этот приём и не используйте его никогда. В конструкции `For I:=1 To Length(Result) Do` длина вычисляется только один раз, перед началом цикла, а не на каждом шаге.

Comment: Хочу обратить внимание, на то, что после IF и замены должны  идти continue. Если бы символы на замену совпадали с теми на что нужно менять, то будет не рабочий код. Например, "а" на "о", "о" на "и" - в итоге "а" поменялось бы сначала на "о", а потом на "и" , ну и все "о" на "и" бы поменялись

Comment: @AlbertFomin +1. А ещё лучше, реализовать выбор через `case`, а не набор `if`.

Comment: А ещё лучше не разводить тут пустые разговоры, это демопример, ответ получен. Интересен был сам факт получения предупреждения, можете оставить одну строку)

Comment: @Isaev Если вы допускаете такие демо-примеры, то и в реальном коде сделаете аналогичную ошибку. Вам указали на то, что ваш код не очень хорош и тут живёт потенциальный баг.

Comment: В вопросе пример кода иллюстрирующий вопрос. Домыслы о том, что было бы **если** у бабушки был .... и какой там реальный код, к делу они не относятся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вот такой код будет корректным и безошибочным:**

```
Function exchange(input: String): String;
Var
  I: Integer;
  sb: TStringBuilder;
Begin
  sb := TStringBuilder.Create(input);
  try
    For I := 0 To sb.Length - 1 Do
    Begin
      if sb.Chars[I] = 'a' Then sb.Chars[I] := 'b';
      if sb.Chars[I] = 'c' Then sb.Chars[I] := 'd';
      if sb.Chars[I] = 'e' Then sb.Chars[I] := 'f';
    End;
    Result := sb.ToString;
  finally
    sb.Free;
  end;
End;
```

**А теперь объяснение:**

В современных версиях Делфы, при внедрении поддержки новых платформ (iOS, Android, x64 и т.п.) было принято решение уходить от строк индексируемых `1 .. N` в пользу стандартных с индексацией `0 .. N-1`. Данное изменение ломает практически весь существующий код. Поэтому его внедрение идет очень медленно и постепенно. В какой-то версии добавили предупреждения, в какой-то `{$IFDEF ZEROBASEDSTRINGS}`. Где-то эта директива включена по умолчанию, но в основном нет.

О чем говорит данное предупреждение - о том, что обращаться к строкам по индексу небезопасно, т.к. индексация может быть заранее неизвестна (в зависимости от директивы и целевой платформы).

**Как быть?**

- Самое простое решение, если вам нужна только Win32 - отключить предупреждения и спокойно жить дальше.
- Самое правильное, если вам нужны новые платформы - переписать код с использованием построителя строк (`TStringBuilder`), который сам разберется как именно строка индексируется, и предоставляет к ней единый интерфейс через свои методы.

P.S. Как ни странно, `For I:=1 To I Do` является вполне корректным кодом, т.к. цикл *сохраняет* максимальное значение *до* начала итерирования.

Comment: вот спасибо, добрый человек, за доступное разъяснение! А то я до сих пор ничего полезного, кроме "отключить предупреждения дерективой компилятора" не слышал. Теперь буду писать правильный код)

Comment: @Isaev сам открыл для себя много нового пока писал ответ, так что и вам спасибо за интересный вопрос. А писать лучше так, как целесообразно. Я, например, варнинги отключил и сам проверяю индексацию, ибо заводить построитель строк на каждый чих выглядит несколько накладным.

Comment: это привычка с института, там учили, что правильный код должен компилироваться без варнунгов). Через построитель вроде и работает быстрее, он при добавлении символа в конец не пересоздаёт строку, память выделяется тоже не по элеементно, а заранее блоками. можно в класс вынести работу через него, чтобы не выглядело накладно

Answer (score 2):

Как было сказано выше, варнинг появляется из-за того, что современные версии Delphi стали поддерживать различные платформы, на которых нумерация строк сделана с `0`, а не с `1`, как это было раньше на Win32. И теперь, чтобы код работал на всех платформах, каноничный способ итерироваться по строкам заключается в использовании функций `Low` и `High`:

```
function Exchange(const AInput: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := AInput;
  for I := Low(Result) to High(Result) do begin
    if Result[I] = 'a' then Result[I] := 'b' else
    if Result[I] = 'c' then Result[I] := 'd' else
    if Result[I] = 'e' then Result[I] := 'f';
  end;
end;
```

Однако, данный способ сработает только в Delphi XE3 и выше, а вот в XE2 и ниже, будут ошибки:

```
E2198 Low cannot be applied to a long string
E2198 High cannot be applied to a long string
```

И если вдруг хочется поддерживать старые версии Delphi, то придётся написать свои обёртки над этими функциями и использовать их:

```
function StrLow(const S: string): Integer; inline;
begin
  Result := {$IFDEF XE3UP} Low(S) {$ELSE} 1 {$ENDIF};
end;

function StrHigh(const S: string): Integer; inline;
begin
  Result := {$IFDEF XE3UP} High(S) {$ELSE} Length(S) {$ENDIF};
end;
```

Однако, и здесь есть подводный камень - если вы вдруг в какой-то функции захотите временно включить/выключить поддержку новых строк через директиву `ZEROBASEDSTRINGS` и вызвать одну из этих функций, то вы получите ошибку, т.к. они будут выдавать результат в не зависимости от этой настройки (будут использоваться глобальные настройки этой директивы). Поэтому, просто не стоит управлять руками этой директивой внутри своих функций/юнитов.

Подробное обсуждение вопроса о написании обратно-совместимого кода см. тут: [How to work with 0-based strings in a backwards compatible way since Delphi XE5?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510379/6219657)

Comment: Спасибо что напомнили про моё альтернативное решение и дополнительные подводные камни! =)